# Tonejs Transport error in pausing while songs are playing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api

So I'm trying to make a simple Digital audio workstation(D.A.W) kind of thing in react.
To solve this problem I'm using Tonejs Transport to play and sync multiple songs on Transport timeline and is working fine but problem arises when i try to pause it. Eventually it pauses when i click to pause but also it crashes the application saying **Error: buffer is either not set or not loaded**

I tried to do something like this but this  didn't solve the problem.

```
  Tone.Buffer.on('load', () => {
  if (this.props.play)
  Tone.Transport.start()
  if (!this.props.play) 
    Tone.Transport.stop()
    })
```

This is where I'm setting the player

```
Player = (src, startTime,volume) => {

    Tone.Transport.bpm.value = 108;
    Tone.Transport.loop = false;
    let buff = new Tone.Buffer({
      "url": `/MP3s/${src}`,

    });
    let play = new Tone.Player(buff).toMaster().sync().start(startTime)

Tone.Buffer.on('load', () => {

      if (this.props.play)
      Tone.Transport.start()
      if (!this.props.play) 
        Tone.Transport.stop()

  })
   }
```

It's showing error on the let play line in code and i just couldn't figure out on my own about the reason of problem and how to resolve it. Also I'm playing these files from the public folder of my react app.